# How to Trigger Stock Status Index?

Tags: magento-1, stock, indexing, indexer, stock-status

We're using Mass Product Update in the admin, however, this doesn't trigger stock status.

I can use observer once `catalog_product_attribute_update_before` is called, and manually trigger indexer there. But I don't know how:

```
cataloginventory_stock_status_idx
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start indexers from the backend or from the shell.

Goto {Magnetoinstalldir}/shell and invoke `php indexer.php --reindex cataloginventory_stock`

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this.

1) You can go to admin panel and reindex the desired status.

2) You can also reindex from **Command Line Interface**  using the indexes listing below.

```
catalog_product_attribute     Product Attributes
catalog_product_price         Product Prices
catalog_url                   Catalog Url Rewrites
catalog_product_flat          Product Flat Data
catalog_category_flat         Category Flat Data
catalog_category_product      Category Products
catalogsearch_fulltext        Catalog Search Index
cataloginventory_stock        Stock status
```

- Here is the complete command for reindexing.

> php -f /path-to-magento/indexer.php -- -reindex cataloginventory_stock